# How to get the "stack trace" during string interpolation in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have some functions that write code as strings (for templating purposes) and I want these to be able to automatically keep indents correct.

Rather than having to tell each function call what indent depth this call is from, I'd prefer it to be able to automatically detect it.

I thought i might be able to use Get-PSCallStack but this doesn't seem to treat string interpolation as part of the stack. I see this if there is an exception as it doesn't tell me where in the string the exception interpolation happened. However when there is an exception, I can use `gerr -Newest 2` and this does contain the actual line number of the string in the template to give me a chance of debugging. I'm not sure how to reproduce this "newest 2" behaviour at runtime however

So this works

```
function Get-PosInString {
    param($SomeParam)
    # debug to see where it thinks we are in the stack trace
    (Get-PSCallStack)[1] | format-list | Out-String
    (Get-PSCallStack)[1].position | format-list | Out-String
    
    # actual output of this function
    Write-Output (((Get-PSCallStack)[1]).Position.StartOffset - 2) # -2 as there is always a $( at the beginning

}

"hello $(Get-PosInString)"
```

ultimately returns the correct value "7"

```
ScriptName       :
ScriptLineNumber : 1
InvocationInfo   : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
Position         : Get-PosInString
FunctionName     : <ScriptBlock>
Command          : <ScriptBlock>
Location         : <No file>
Arguments        : {}


File                :
StartScriptPosition : System.Management.Automation.Language.InternalScriptPosition
EndScriptPosition   : System.Management.Automation.Language.InternalScriptPosition
StartLineNumber     : 1
StartColumnNumber   : 10
EndLineNumber       : 1
EndColumnNumber     : 25
Text                : Get-PosInString
StartOffset         : 9
EndOffset           : 24

 7
```

however if I then do some additional interpolation on one of the input args to the function (which I also need to be able to do)

```
"hello $(Get-PosInString "$('argvalue')")"
```

I get result

```
hello
ScriptName       :
ScriptLineNumber : 1
InvocationInfo   : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
Position         : 'argvalue'
FunctionName     : <ScriptBlock>
Command          : <ScriptBlock>
Location         : <No file>
Arguments        : {}


File                :
StartScriptPosition : System.Management.Automation.Language.InternalScriptPosition
EndScriptPosition   : System.Management.Automation.Language.InternalScriptPosition
StartLineNumber     : 1
StartColumnNumber   : 41
EndLineNumber       : 1
EndColumnNumber     : 46
Text                : 'argvalue'
StartOffset         : 40
EndOffset           : 45

 38
```

which is now taking the last stack item to be the parameter I passed in and it doesn't seem possible to get to the stack of the item that actually called the function.

This feels to me like a powershell bug. I would expect that the interpolation of the caller argument should have been dealt with during the call, and with the execution point now past that and inside the function, the stack should be consistent regardless of any parameter interpolation on the call.

To this end, I have create a bug https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21167

Comment: You want the starting offset of the parent `$(...)`, relative to the opening quote of the containing string literal? That'll require re-parsing the whole command, it's gonna get very messy - not to mention its excessively expensive to fetch the call stack at runtime, especially if its deep. Perhaps if you show us an example of code-generating code in which this is to be used, we can suggest better alternatives

Comment: thanks for the pointer on performance, that is a definate consideration here. Ultimately I have a bunch of ps template files that are essentially a HERE string that is called by Invoke-Expression in a loop to produce a bunch of code files. All the repeated patterns are stored as other functions and called using $(...) inside those templates. While the first line of the output from those functions stays at the same position, if the function returns additional rows, I have to put them at the right indent depth. Been doing it with a int param but easy to get wrong so looking for improved approach

Comment: Sounds like you could just place the `$(...)` expressions in the here-strings at the offset the resulting code should be indented to? Can you show an example?

Comment: yes, but if the function has to return multiple rows in the output string, rows two onwards will all be non-indented unless I do something in the function to indent them

Comment: You could write a wrapper function that takes the expected indentation width as argument and then rewrites the resulting code with whitespace prefixing each individual line. It'll be easier to suggest an optimal solution once you show us an example :)

Comment: Avoid using [automatic variable `$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input) as a regular one…

Comment: the existing functions already require being told how deep the indent needs to be by param. I was trying to eliminate the need for that by having powershell tell me what position the interpolation ```$(...) ``` starts on. A simple repro of the wider solution is not trivial to provide and does start to take us away from the real question which is, shouldn't powershell be able to give the stack frame consistently in the two scenario's I've shown. BTW, I've traced it and I can't see a huge performance impact when using Get-PSCallStack the way I intended.

Comment: @JosefZ while correct to suggest to avoid it, $input was just for the minimal repro and doesn't impact the behaviour. I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

- Indeed, you've found a *bug*, present up to at least PowerShell 7.4.1, which you've since reported in [GitHub issue #21167](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21167).
- The bug itself is unrelated to any involvement of [expandable (interpolating), double-quoted string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), and comes down to use of `$(...)`, a [subexpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) (by contrast, using an [*array* subexpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), `@(...)` (which isn't supported inside `"..."`), is *not* affected).

The **gist of the bug** is that using `$(...)` in an *argument* passed to a command causes the loss of call-stack information seen by that command via the [`Get-PSCallStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-pscallstack) cmdlet, as shown in the following simplified example:

```bash
function Foo { [string] (Get-PSCallStack)[1].Position }

# !! The $(...)-enclosed argument breaks the call stack-reporting
Foo $('hi')
```

The above:

- *should* output `Foo $('hi')`, i.e. the source code of the `Foo` call.
- *actually* outputs (as of v7.4.1) `'hi'`

That is, the one and only call stack element of the *nested* pipeline inside `$(...)` effectively and unexpectedly *replaced* the one of the `Foo` invocation.

---

###### Additional information:

- Commands inside `$(...)` and `@(...)` run in *nested pipelines* and do *not* see the call stack of their *callers* - their call stacks starts with what is passed *to them*; e.g., the following reports just the source code of what's *inside `$(...)`*, not also the enclosing `Write-Output` call:

  ```bash
   # -> '[string] (Get-PSCallStack).Position'
   Write-Output $([string] (Get-PSCallStack).Position)
  ```
- However, even commands inside `$(...)` and `@(...)` can determine their own *lexical* context via `Get-PSCallStack`, namely in terms of the *position in the enclosing source code*, which is what your first example demonstrates:

  - This lexical context is reflected in the [`.Position`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.callstackframe.position#system-management-automation-callstackframe-position) property of the [`System.Management.Automation.CallStackFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CallStackFrame) instances returned by `Get-PSCallStack`: It contains the lexical position of the subexpression inside the enclosing script (block).
  - Your first example relies on that, but note that `(Get-PSCallStack)[1].Position.StartOffset - 2` returning `7` implies that you must have executed `Get-PosInString` *as the very first line* of your script, after having defined the function separately, *earlier*. If you place the function definition first in the same script, as implied by the example, the result would be `375` (in a script with Unix-format LF-only  newlines).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the significance of the bottom two bullet points. Are you suggesting that when this bug is fixed, it will change the behaviour of the first example (that currently works) and make it so that it will no longer work. If so are you saying that there really is no way to identify the character position of the $() expression so i can have the called function automatically indent to the same depth? I'm building on Windows, not Unix, so CRLF files.

Comment: @Brett, no the bug fix should not impact the lexical-position reporting.  I added the information merely to clarify how this reporting works, given that future readers may be tempted to think that the position reported is _relative to the enclosing `"..."`_, which isn't the case. As noted, if you place your first snippet as-is in a `.ps1` script and execute it, the result is `375` (with LF-only newlines), not `7`, as stated in your question.

Comment: @Brett: With CRLF newlines, it would be `386`. Either way, if you wanted extract substrings by position, you'd need to read the entire script as a whole (e.g. with `Get-Content -Raw`, so that the original newlines are preserved.